# Display none to All div by loop and display a perticular div which I want to show

Tags: javascript, html

I am using Javascrip and I have a function like the following where I want to hide all div. But I don't know why this code is not working. Will anyone help me with this?

Javasvript

```
 function showDiv(divTag,id)
    {
     var i;
      for(i=1;i<7;i++)
     {
       document.getElementById(divTag+i).style.display = 'none';
     }
      document.getElementById(divTag+id).style.display = 'block';
    }
```

or

```
function showDiv(divTag,id)
{
  var i;
  for(i=1;i<5;i++)
 {
   var tempDiv = divTag + i;
   document.getElementById(tempDiv).style.display = 'none';
 }
document.getElementById(divTag+id).style.display = 'block';
}
```

And HTML

```
 <a href="#" onClick="showDiv(\"hide_\",1)">Show Only Div1</a>
    <div id="hide_1">
    Abc
    </div>
     <a href="#" onClick="showDiv(\"hide_\",2)">Show Only Div2</a>

    <div id="hide_2">
    BCD
    </div>
<a href="#" onClick="showDiv(\"hide_\",3)">Show Only Div2</a>

    <div id="hide_3">
    EDF
    </div>
<a href="#" onClick="showDiv(\"hide_\",4)">Show Only Div2</a>

    <div id="hide_4">
    FGE
    </div>
```

Both of the abov process I have tried but failed to do that

Comment: also can you please describe what you are planning to do? so that I will work on the code and edit my post with the same :-)

Answer (score 1):

Several things:

1. The `"onclick"` (not `"onClick"`) is the correct way to assign the click event handler in both html and JavaScript.
2. You are looping from 1 to 6 in `for(i=1;i<7;i++)` line of the first function, but you only have 4 elements in your html. When reaching the non-existing fifth - your code will throw an error. Something along the lines of "TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null".
3. As @verisimilitude has mentioned, you have a syntax error in your html where you put a quoted text inside another text that's quoted in the same way. It should be `onclick="showDiv('hide_',1)"`. Note the single quotes around 'hide_'.

Here's the code that works. **[Click here to see it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/mwQmx/2/)**.

**Here's your JavaScript function:**

```
// Please note that it must be in the global scope
// otherwise you won't be able to call it from your html.

function showDiv(divTag, id) {
  var i;
  for (i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    var tempDiv = divTag + i;
    document.getElementById(tempDiv).style.display = 'none';
  }
  document.getElementById(divTag+id).style.display = 'block';
}
```

Also, take a look at **[another working version of your code](http://jsfiddle.net/mwQmx/3/)** that pre-validates the existence of your elements before hiding/showing them. So you don't have to worry about your `for` loop iterating over elements that have been removed.

**And here's your html:**

```
<a href="#" onclick="showDiv('hide_', 1);">Show Only Div1</a>
<div id="hide_1">Div1</div>

<a href="#" onclick="showDiv('hide_', 2);">Show Only Div2</a>
<div id="hide_2">Div2</div>

<a href="#" onclick="showDiv('hide_', 3);">Show Only Div3</a>
<div id="hide_3">Div3</div>

<a href="#" onclick="showDiv('hide_', 4);">Show Only Div4</a>
<div id="hide_4">Div4</div>​
```

Comment: +1. for the first point that you mentioned. I think we should constantly strive for XHTML compliance and have lowercase HTML attributes. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" onClick="showDiv("hide_",1)">Show Only Div1</a>
```

yields a javascript syntax error. This should be

```
<a href="#" onClick="showDiv('hide_',1)">Show Only Div1</a>
```

Check the single quotes around "hide_"

Comment: care to update the above question with what you're really looking for? Moreover, it was a syntax error that was coming up when I copy + pasted your code in my editor which I corrected.

Comment: I did not copy and paste the cose. I wrote it here so I did some mistakes.

Comment: @user1379021 If you didn't copy-paste your code exactly, how can we even debug it?? Anyway, did you try the solution I suggested in the other answer?

Comment: Yes. @Oleg has explained everything properly step-by-step in his previous answer. I even asked you to functionally describe what you exactly want so that we may guide you.